# How do add class name and method to rails logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I have a rails app I want to add a custom log formatter to. In the logs, I want to dynamically show the class where code was called and the method that called it.  I don't see a straightforward way to do this in the [Rails Logger docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Format).  Currently, in the initialize method of classes in my app I'm doing `@logger = self.progname` to get the class and `@logger.level("#{__callee__}: some message"` to get the method.

I can write a custom logging class and assign it to `config.log_formatter` in `.../config/environments/production.rb` which is fine. How can I add a formatter that will dynamically tell me what class and what method I'm in when I log stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the class will be reflected by the `self` object, although this could be tricky.  I think typically you want the class of self, for an instance method, but for a singleton (class) method you want that `self`.

So you might use

```
self.kind_of?(Class) ? self.name : self.class.name
```

Looks like you are already using `__callee__` to get the method.

Comment: You don't strictly need `self.` above, but I think this code is more clear than `kind_of?(Class) ? name : self.class.name`.

Comment: the goal would be so I dont need to define it within each class, but define it in the `../config/environments/production.rb` file (or a more appropriate place) so when rails goes through its initialization process, the log formatter already knows to get the class and method every time i log something.  Something like what [this person](https://medium.com/@yuliaoletskaya/standardize-rails-log-output-d6ad0827a172#file-application-rb) did with `source_class`, although binding_of_caller is only recommended for debugging

Comment: I found one way to get the class here that worked for me. They use the `binding_of_caller` gem to get the class name. Then they use a custom log formatter that writes it out. https://medium.com/@yuliaoletskaya/standardize-rails-log-output-d6ad0827a172